# How to connect to database connection pools of weblogic server from a standalone java application

Tags: java, weblogic

I have a stand alone java application and there is a weblogic server running on a different physical machine. Is there a way I can connect to weblogic database connection pools from standalone java application(not part of weblogic, altogether a different java application)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/luzmestre/how-to-connect-to-weblogic-datasource-from-a-java-client), and just replace the context provider hashtable entry with the URL or ip address of your machine running the weblogic database.

It will only work if that machine is connected to the internet and it's firewall allows connections to it